# SQL Server 2008 ORDER BY Error on sqlsrv php driver

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a query to filter results by distance based on lng and lat stored in table:

```
SELECT *, (3960 * acos( cos( radians( 51.8026795 ) ) * cos( radians( advert.lat ) ) * cos( radians( advert.lng ) - radians( -0.7201327 ) ) + 
sin( radians( 51.8026795 ) ) * sin( radians( advert.lat ) ) ) ) AS Distance 
FROM advert 
INNER JOIN photo ON advert.id = photo.advertid 
WHERE photo.main = 'True' AND advert.status<>0 
ORDER BY advert.price ASC
```

This works fine in SQL Server Management Studio and returns the right values, however when I use the exact same query in PHP using `sqlsrv` driver I get:

> Error in executing query.   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000
>   [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1](http://www.developerdream.com) => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'AND'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'. ) )

Have I done something really simple to fix?!

You can see the problem at [DeveloperDream.com](http://www.developerdream.com) by clicking search then entering a postcode

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're certain it is this query causing the error and not a different one?

Comment: Copy your code into a text editor that can view hex chars, and look to see if there's some non-printable character between `True` and `AND` that's breaking the query.

Comment: Here is the query: $tsql = "SELECT photo.*, advert.*, ( 3960 * acos( cos( radians( ".$_SESSION['lat']." ) ) * cos( radians( advert.lat ) ) * cos( radians( advert.lng ) - radians( ".$_SESSION['lng']." ) ) + sin( radians( ".$_SESSION['lat']." ) ) * sin( radians( advert.lat ) ) ) ) AS Distance FROM advert INNER JOIN photo ON advert.id = photo.advertid WHERE photo.main = 'True' AND advert.status<>0 ORDER BY advert.price ASC";

Comment: Tried echo'ing $tsql and pasting back into MS Management and executes fine...

Comment: Also if I take out 'ORDER BY advert.price ASC' from $tsql it works fine...

Comment: What is the datatype of `photo.main`?

Comment: photo.main is bit data type, tried =1 as well with no luck

Comment: Are you building your query dynamically? Searching for postcode `xxx` gives a different error.

Comment: Yes, I just want to get the ORDER BY issue sorted then i'll sort out some error handling on postcodes that do not geocode.. it's driving me crazy!!

Comment: Perhaps it is a crazy idea, but have you tried using aliases for the tables?

Comment: Gordon, i'm self-taught and have not self-taught aliases, i'm googling now...

Comment: OK, tried alias names on tables with no luck, would storing this as a procedure in SQL Management studio then calling it from php work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - there was another search term being added to the end of the query erroneously but not being echo'd, thanks michael for suggesting this in the very first instance